# Users who have switched from Parse to OneSignal, how are you handling the migration?

Tags: parse-platform, migration, onesignal

I've got switches in place to deprecate access to old versions of the app, which I'm considering turning on to prevent people who might have an old version of the app that's still pointed to parse.

I'll be waiting to make the changes to the backend to only make OneSignal push notifications after both apps go live in the store.

Have you created a custom cron job to handle incoming new users to Parse, then export that to OneSignal?

Answer (score -1):

OneSignal's Parse Data Importer can be used multiple times, and will merge in any new data without duplication. So you can import your users now, then import again later to load in any new Parse subscribers.

Comment: You didnt answer the question